# failed to find tag `latest` - pallet version in tutorial

Tags: documentation

Many tutorial on the [substrate doc](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/) have similar code for the `Cargo.toml`.

For example this is from [configure the contracts pallet tutoria](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/)

```
[dependencies.pallet-contracts]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
tag = 'latest'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

[dependencies.pallet-contracts-primitives]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
tag = 'latest'
version = '4.0.0-dev'
```

If I try to compile I get the following error:

```
failed to get `pallet-contracts` as a dependency of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `pallet-contracts`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=latest

Caused by:
  failed to find tag `latest`

Caused by:
  reference 'refs/remotes/origin/tags/latest' not found; class=Reference (4); code=NotFound (-3)
```

If I set the branch like this `branch = polkadot-v0.9.24` it works.

I think the problem is that there isn't a `latest` tag in the `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git` repo.

Is this a problem of the documentation or I miss something?

Comment: Please file an issue for ... Issues on the docs 

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its no linger an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tag will be deprecated for the time being, it was not meant to be deleted just yet, all versions will be following Polkadot releases as you say, so for now, always inspect the docs and update the template source to the matching release tag to ensure compatibility.

Comment: This has been implemented https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/pull/1264